# Why does my CSS transition wait for another to finish before starting?

Tags: css, animation, sass, transition

I am trying to do this project where I showcase what you can do with just SASS and HTML. No JavaScript. However, one of my animations is acting strange and I can't seem to figure out why. I click on the navigation to start the animation, and it just disappears. Then, once the words disappear, the animation starts and finishes.

I have tried removing the bezier times. I have tried messing with the transition settings changing the values from all to transform. I have tried messing with the timing (.4s to 2s).

// HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
<input type="checkbox" class="navigation__checkbox" id="navi-toggle">
    <label for="navi-toggle" class="navigation__button">
        <span class="navigation__icon">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
    <!-- background for animation  -->
<div class="navigation__background">&nbsp;</div>
    <!-- navigation for page  -->
<nav class="navigation__nav">
    <ul class="navigation__list">
        <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link"> <span>01</span>  About Natours</a></li>
        <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link"> <span>02</span>  Your Benefits</a></li>
        <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link"> <span>03</span>  Popular Tours</a></li>
        <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link"> <span>04</span>  Stories</a></li>
        <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link"> <span>05</span>  Book Tour</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

// Original state of the button

```
&__background {
        height: 6rem;
        width: 6rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 6.5rem;
        right: 6.5rem;
        background-image: radial-gradient($color-primary-light, $color-primary-dark);
        z-index: 1000;
        transition: transform .8s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    }
```

// Once animation starts

```
&__checkbox:checked ~ &__background {
        transform: scale(200);
    }
```

What is suppose to happen is when the user clicks on the button, the background should expand across the entire screen, and the navigation links should slide in from left. Then, once the user closes the navigation, the navigation links should slide out left, and the background should contract at the same time.

Comment: You need to provide us with your HTML.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to create SO snippets that only consist of CSS code - there's nothing to see...

Comment: Yes, I would have fixed that if I could figure out how to edit my dang post :P working on it now.

Comment: Does giving a start point of `transform: none` in `&__background` help?

Comment: No, it seems the issue is still there :(